# Is lean non-hyperandrogenic polycystic ovary syndrome genetic?

Tags: endocrinology, genetics, gynecology, pcos

I read many papers that address the genetic factor of polycystic ovary syndrome (PCOS). But all the papers I have been through focus on classic PCOS with hyperparathyroidism and insulin resistance. I am curious whether these genetics play a role in women without an insulin problem or elevated androgen levels, but have PCO and problems with ovulation (because of the ratio LH/FSH or something else), who are, according to the Rotterdam diagnostic criteria, affected with PCOS.